# Replicating this tile using CSS3 Tranformations

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a isometric tile engine just using `<div>` tags.

I've seen numerous isometric tiling engines for HTML5 but they are either poorly documented nor what I expected them to be (i.e. most are asking me to download freeware to develop on).

I'm trying to replicate this image in CSS3:

[image: Basic Isometric Tile]

When trying to `transform: rotate(deg)` a div in CSS, I noticed that this tile is not equilateral, so the div box surpassed the image:

[image]

Can anybody shed some light on this?

Comment: If you plan to fill such tile with some content, rotation may be a problem.
May be it's better to use some image with alfa-channel(PNG) as a background for regular div without any rotation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this helps. I also have a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zL4dem7j/).

```css
div {
  background: #dedede;
  width: 50px;
  height:50px;
  margin: 20px;
  transform: rotateX(60deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: This is a perfect representation of what I asked. Thank you.